# Populate User Name and Email to a URL

Tags: apex, visualforce

So I am trying to populate User name and email onto a URL.

I have a button on a custom object which will re-direct me to a Visualforce page with few fields where on hitting save will fill a URL(google form).

So I want to pre-fill username and email without having them enter it and have the values onto the URL

I tried using merge fields {!User.Email} on the URL but it did not work.

Comment: Pls share current code, so that we can suggest modifications.

Comment: Victor for the current code I don't have anything that relates to what I am asking but here's  my URL below for better understanding. https://docs.google.com/a/mycompany.com/forms/d/112GYhKbx5Ux833UDI_dEA1yL2eHuW0pr5blOymLoRsg/formResponse?ifq&entry.1865812496='+dept+'&entry.399734918='+Email+'&entry.571044671&entry.488162040&entry.1220858109&entry.449060360&entry.776835233&entry.754748200='+name+'&entry.1408822280='{!User.Email}'&entry.315413522='+desc+'&entry.1366373962='+info+'&entry.1716955237='+steps+'&entry.1435223618='+severity+'&submit=Submit

Comment: Sounds like you need to use urlencode: {!URLENCODE(User.Email)}

Comment: Hi Mark, so I tried that and I am receiving "Error: Unknown property 'Escalations__cStandardController.User' "    Escalations__c - is the name of the custom object. Does this mean I need the query the UserID and Email in the apex ? if so can you help me with that  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try {!$User.Email}. The $ is important if you're trying to grab the logged in user in a button.

URLENCODE is not a bad idea, but maybe not necessary.

Comment: I'm receiving this error Error: Unknown property 'Escalations__cStandardController.userId'

Comment: Where are you getting this error? When trying to save the VF page? $User is a global variable as documented [here](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global.htm). I'm not sure what might be wrong. Can you post the code?

Comment: Hey Ryan, my bad it did worked great it was a different part of the code that was causing this issue (javascript) Thanks so much for your answer !